# $G$ is a finite group, Show that if $[G:Z(G)] = 21$ then exists $H ,K < G$ such that $H\neq G$ and $K \neq G$ and $HK = G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to use the correspondence-theorem in order to prove it.

> $G$ is a finite group, Show that if $[G:Z(G)] = 21$ then exists $H ,K < G$ such that $H\neq G$ and $K \neq G$ and $HK = G$.

Comment: I guess the original formulation is *"there exist **abelian** subgroups $H, K < G$..."*

Comment: You also need to place a question in the body; a title should summarize the question but it should not **be** the question.

Comment: Nice point, @AndreasCaranti...and good hint, too. Though I'd rather first go for *abelian subgroups in the quotient...* +1

Comment: There is no need to assume that $G$ is finite. Why do so many questions assume this unnecessarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your concern is not to show that any such group exists, I think this is a no-brainer. In the quotient $G/Z(G)$ there exist elements of order $3$ and $7$ respectively (by Cauchy's theorem), and the two together cannot fail to generate all of $G/Z(G)$ (by Lagrange's theorem). Choosing representatives $h,k$ in $G$ of the generators of these two cyclic subgroups of $G/Z(G)$, the groups $H=\langle h,Z(G)\rangle$ and $K=\langle k,Z(G)\rangle$ clearly fit the bill. Also being generated by the center and one more element, they are clearly Abelian.

Comment: +1, the logic of the question does not indeed require to show that there is a centreless group of order $21$.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two groups of order $\;21\;$ up to isomorphism, and since for **any** group the quotient $\;G/Z(G)\;$ *cannot* be cyclic non-trivial, we have that **it must be** that
$G/Z(G)\cong C_7\rtimes C_3\;$ , with $\;C_n\;$ the cyclic group of order n, and $\;\rtimes=\;$ semidirect product, and in this case it means

$$H:=C_7\lhd G/Z(G)\;\;,\;\;K:=C_3\le G/Z(G)\;\;,\;\;H\cap K=1\;\;,\;\;HK=G/Z(G)$$

Well, apply now the correspondence theorem...